# how to send Array of form data(Object) as json

Tags: jquery, json

In [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tribhuwan/Mv9MY/11/)
I have given one sample, I am trying to get JSON data but it is not as expected.

```
{"txtTitle":["Tribhuwan","Pankaj"],"txtName":["Dewangan","Sharma"]
,"seGender":["Male","Male"]}
```

I want this data as `{[{"txtTitle":"Tribhuwan","txtName":"Dewangan","seGender":"Male"},
{"txtTitle":"Pankaj","txtName":"Sharma","seGender":"Male"}]}`
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the server will combine the duplicate keys anyway, is there a specific problem you are trying to solve with that format?

Comment: I think you need to switch your `[]` and `{}` in your expected output.

Comment: Given JSON is just a rough idea, please check the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you desire is [invalid](http://jsonlint.com/)

If you can live with an output of

```
[{"txtTitle":"Tribhuwan","txtName":"Pankaj","seGender":"Male"},{"txtTitle":"Dewangan","txtName":"Sharma","seGender":"Male"}]
```

Then this serializeObject method from the linked [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tribhuwan/Mv9MY/11/) could work

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = [];
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    var t = {};
    $.each(a, function() {

        if(t[this.name] !== undefined){
            o.push(t);
            t = {};
        }

        t[this.name] = this.value;        
    });
    o.push(t);
    return o;
};
```

Comment: My JS foo is pitiful, but that should be the general idea.  Someone please clean that up as needed.

Comment: The sample json is written by my self, it is not perfect.   What i want is array of object ( where object contains first name, last name and gender), so that i can directly convert it into java object

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject myjson ;
JSONArray the_json_array;
StringBuilder builder = ... your jason content by buffer .....
            String a = "{child:"+builder.toString()+"}";
            myjson = new JSONObject(a);
            the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("child");
            int size = the_json_array.length();
            ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                JSONObject another_json_object =  the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    arrays.add(another_json_object);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("ClientProtocolException :"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException :"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("JSONException :"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrays;
```

i just hope this serves you , kind of did the favour to me , i was having my sontent via a httppost client response , storing in the builder variable.